# sorting through a dataset with javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a button to sort a sort a dynamic data-set that was invoked by PHP. Right now I am just trying to put a button in that arranges them by highest item.

in catalog.view.php

```
 <div class="pricing-buttons">
    <button type="button" class="highest btn btn-outline- 
 primary">highest price</button> <button type="button" class="lowest 
  btn btn-outline-info">lowest price</button>
  </div>
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
       <?php if (isset($items)) { ?>
        <?php foreach ( $items as $item) : ?>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <article class="cards">
                              <div class="col-12">


 <section class="card-holder" id="<?php echo $item['code']; ?>">


 <section class="card code">

 <ul>

  <h2 class="cat-order-code bottom-drop center" 
 data-code="<?php echo $item['code']; ?>">Code: <?php echo $item['code']; ?></h2>


<h3 class="cat-order-name center"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></h3>


 <img class="cat-order-image thumbnail box-image-width" 
 src="<?php echo IMAGES .  $item['image']; ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $item['description']; ?>">


  <!-- part I am working on here the data-value ['price'] -->                                                    
 <li class="cat-order-price" data-value="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>">Price:
 <?php echo $price = ($item['price'] == 0 ? 'Make offer' :  '$' . $item['price']);
 ?></li>


 <h4 class="cat-order-sold sale" data-sold="<?php echo $item['sold']; ?>">
 <?php echo $sold = ($item['sold'] == 0 ? 'For Sale' : 'sold'); ?></h4>


 <a class="cat-order-btn btn btn-lg btn-outline-danger btn-width 
 center-block"  href='details.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>'>
 <?php echo $item['id']; ?></a>

  </ul>

  </section>

 </section>

 </div>

 </article>

 </div>

 </div>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

 <?php } ?>

 </div>

 </section>
```

I am working in chuncks, since I am still new to JAvaScript and Es6.
so far in my javascript file I  have

```
 const highest = document.querySelector('.highest');
 const priceValue = 
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]');
 const price = priceValue;
 price.map(price => price.dataset.value);
 console.log(price);
```

My question is why is the map not working out? I know i have a long ways to go to get where I want, but I am trying to understand why my map function is coming back with the same value as the Array.from function?

any help would be thankful.

Comment: Pro-tip: If you need JS help, skip the PHP. Rendered HTML is more helpful.

Comment: what do you mean by rendered html ?

Comment: JS doesn't act on the PHP, it acts on the HTML. Whatever the PHP produces is what's going to be relevant to any JS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the result of the `map` operation to a variable, like so

```
const result = price.map(price => price.dataset.value);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to sort the values array you can now sort it with [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```
result.sort();
```

Also, having an element variable with the same name as the array may get confusing. This would be a more readable alternative

```
const result = price.map(p => p.dataset.value);
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for... im sorry if i did not know how to say it correctly. but you broke it down really well. it gave me not the array, but the numbers from the data-set.